# Repeat in gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

Two queries related to gremlin are as follows:

1. Want to stop the traversal when a condition is satisfied during repeated condition check.

```
g.V().has('label_','A')).emit().repeat(inE().outV()).until(has('stop',1)).project('depth','values').by(valueMap('label_','stop'))
```

I want the query to stop returning further values when the stop is equal to 1 for the node encountered during the repeat statement. But the query doesn't stop and return all the records.
Output required:

```
=>{label_='A',stop=0}
=>{label_='B',stop=0}
=>{label_='C',stop=1}
```

2. Query to return traversal values in the following format considering if edge exists between them. Considering the graph as A->E1->B->E2->C. The output must be as follows

```
=> A,E1,B
=> B,E2,C
```

A, B, C, E1, E2 represents properties respectively where is the starting node

Comment: Could you please provide a Graph example? you can create one in gremlify.com or add a gremlin script that generates some data.

Comment: g.addV().property('label_','A').property('stop',0).addV().property('label_','B').property('stop',0).addV().property('label_','C').property('stop',1) similar for edges between A to B and B to C

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, it seems you traversing on the in edges and not on the out is this on purpose?  if so replace the `out()` in the repeat to `in`

```
g.V().has(label, 'A').emit().
  repeat(out()).until(has('stop', 1)).
  project('label', 'stop').
    by(label).
    by(values('stop'))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ma2xkkszkzr/1

for the second part, I'm still not sure what you meant if you just want to get all edges with their out and in you can use `elementMap`:

```
g.E().elementMap()
```

example:  https://gremlify.com/ma2xkkszkzr/4

and if not supported you can maybe do something like this:

```
g.E().local(union(
      outV(),
      identity(),
      inV()
    ).label().fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ma2xkkszkzr/2

Comment: For the first part, I need to return edges attributes to but not mentioned as it will be complicated. Are the edges causing the issue and until not working for it?
For the second part, the format required is node -> edge -> node. i.e A->E1->B and this will start at A and continue till the edge exist using repeat.

Comment: tired the solution for the first approach until is still not working. The repeat condition is as follows: repeat(inE().outV())

Comment: @Phoenix in the first example if you start in A the direction is out. you need to run `outE().inV()`